# Execute a command on local system when a command on remote system completes

Tags: shell, ssh

Sometimes, when I execute a long command on my computer, I suffix it with `&& notify-send "It's finally done!"`. Is there any way I could do this from an ssh session? I'm aware I could do a one line ssh, e.g. `ssh remotehost "long-term-command" && notify-send "It's finally done!`, but I'd rather not as I'm executing many long-term commands and this seems clunky and inefficient.

If I wanted to notify-send on the remote system, I'd set `DISPLAY` to `:0`. Is there something similar I could do for the opposite?

Answer (score 1):

[X11 Forwarding?](http://en.tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html) Then, run `$ long-command && notify-send "finished"` from the server, w
hich should be displayed on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the command into `batch` or `at now`.

```
batch <<< "ssh remotehost long-term-command && notify-send 'It is finally done!'"
```

Beware of the quote characters and the enviroment of the shell.
Take a look at `atq` and `atrm` to control the queue.